# Please I'm a bit confused about proving that this sequence is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Suppose xn is a sequence of real numbers satisfying |xn- xn-1|≤ 2^-n for each n ≥ 2. Prove that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Have you learned about Cauchy sequences?

Comment: "|xn- xn-1|", that's equal to $1$, which is not $\le 2^{-n}$, so there's no such sequence.

Comment: Do you mean $|x_n-x_{n-1}|$?

Answer (score 1):

Because convergence in the real numbers is the same as the sequence being Cauchy, you can prove it is Cauchy by induction on the difference between $m$ and $n$ for arbitrary $m,n>N.$ If you need help understanding Cauchy sequences [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148713/understanding-the-definition-of-cauchy-sequence) is a relevant question.

(Hint: If you WLOG assume $m>n$ you can create a triangle inequality chain to find $|x_m-x_n|$ as a geometric sum, then you will be able to find such an N.)